# Returning http status codes in Python CGI

Tags: python, http, cgi

Is it possible to send a status code other than 200 via a python cgi script (such as 301 redirect)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

via cgi script?

```
print "Status:301\nLocation: http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: can you also post http request handler in this case/

Comment: Note also that this won't work if you're running your script via Python's built-in CGIHTTPServer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079589/227651

Comment: @MikeHowsden good point! It seems it is not possible to return status code with python built-in CGIHTTPServer. IMO it is major drawback because returning different status is very common even in quite simple webapps. Fortunately, other web server's behaviour is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Via wsgi application?

```
def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '301 Moved Permanently' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Location','http://example.com')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)

    return []
```