# How to return a 500 HTTP status from a C++ CGI program

Tags: soap, cgi

I have a small "SOAP CGI gatewqay" C++ program that reads an HTTP SOAP request from **cin**, get the request info from it and sends it to the legacy server. Then it taks the response, format it as a SOAP response and write it to **cout**.

In case of an error, it writes a **<SOAP-ENV:Fault>** reponse to **cout**. However, [the SOAP standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383529) says that in case of error, the returned HTTP status should be 500 "Internal Server Error". This SOAP CGI gateway should run on any web server that supports CGI. What is the proper way to set the HTTP status returned by the web server when the CGI returns?

Thanks,
splintor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write a "Status: 500 Internal Server Error" to the headers. This has to be written before any content is written of course.

Comment: Thanks. I found this on other Q&A sites, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833715/returning-http-status-codes-in-python-cgi, but couldn't find any standard that describe this CGI behavior with the Status HTTP header. Is this supported by all web servers supporting CGI?

Comment: It is, as I recall, part of the CGI standard, so it'd be a safe bet.