# return http error code from CGI C module

Tags: c, http, module, cgi

I've a CGI module written in C & for some condition I want to return HTTP error 400 from this module. The problem is - I don't know how to return HTTP error from the module.

Looks like the 'return(-1)' in my module, returns the 500 internal server error. I've tried returning 400 etc. but in vein. I've even tried "printf("Status:400");" before returning -1 (as suggested here: [How to return a 500 HTTP status from a C++ CGI program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318507/how-to-return-a-500-http-status-from-a-c-cgi-program)  ) but that didn't work.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Edit: [solved] I was able to return HTTP error code from the python module (which is called later by this C CGI module). So didn't get to try the suggestion mentioned in comments below. Thanks for offering help, though.

Comment: return `0`, but set the header appropriately - it returns it's own error when the exit code of the script is non-zero

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, in it's exact form.

Answer (score 10):

To return HTTP error 400 to the HTTP client, you have to write the HTTP status line to stdout, like this:

```
printf("Status: 400 Bad Request\n");
```

Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875

The Status header field contains a 3-digit integer result code that
indicates the level of success of the script's attempt to handle the
request.

```
  Status         = "Status:" status-code SP reason-phrase NL
  status-code    = "200" | "302" | "400" | "501" | extension-code
  extension-code = 3digit
  reason-phrase  = *TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks. Never get to try that as the problem got solved the other way. Thanks anyways... :)

Comment: My mistake. I updated my answer. (my previous answer was not CGI compliant, but HTTP compliant suitable for callbacks within HTTP servers like civetweb)

Answer (score -1):

To return HTTP error code from your CGI script, you have to write it into `stdout`, such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("status: 400\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Just the `status: status-code\n\n` is necessary.

Comment: This is wrong. The RFC say `\r\n` is the correct delimiter als "Status: 400"