# Need help on getting different http's status code

Tags: python, gdata-api

I am working on Google Contacts API's (Gdata lib for python)
Can i get sample example codes to get different http's status code like 400, 401 500 etc.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
function _setHTTPStatusCode($code) {
        $code = (int)$code;
        $http_codes = array(
            100=>'100 Continue', 101=>'101 Switching Protocols',
            200=>'200 OK', 201=>'201 Created', 202=>'202 Accepted',
                203=>'203 Non-Authoritative Information',204=>'204 No Content',
                205=>'205 Reset Content', 206=>'206 Partial Content', 
            300=>'300 Multiple Choices', 301=>'301 Moved Permanently', 302=>'302 Found',
                303=>'303 See Other', 304=>'304 Not Modified', 305=>'305 Use Proxy',
                306=>'306 (Unused)', 307=>'307 Temporary Redirect', 
            400=>'400 Bad Request', 401=>'401 Unauthorized', 402=>'402 Payment Required',
                403=>'403 Forbidden', 404=>'404 Not Found', 405=>'405 Method Not Allowed',
                406=>'406 Not Acceptable', 407=>'407 Proxy Authentication Required',
                408=>'408 Request Timeout', 409=>'409 Conflict', 410=>'410 Gone',
                411=>'411 Length Required', 412=>'412 Precondition Failed',
                413=>'413 Request Entity Too Large', 414=>'414 Request-URI Too Long',
                415=>'415 Unsupported Media Type', 416=>'416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
                417=>'417 Expectation Failed',
            500=>'500 Internal Server Error', 501=>'501 Not Implemented',
                502=>'502 Bad Gateway', 503=>'503 Service Unavailable', 
                504=>'504 Gateway Timeout', 505=>'505 HTTP Version Not Supported'
        );
        if (!in_array($code, array_keys($http_codes))) $code = 500;
        header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $http_codes[$code]);
    }
```

If you want to test your code against different HTTP codes, just put that in a PHP file and make requests to that. If you're looking for the codes themselves, well, there they are.

See also: [Returning http status codes in Python CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833715/returning-http-status-codes-in-python-cgi)