# Python Redirect not working

Tags: python, cgi

I'm trying to redirect the user to my homepage. Its suppose to be as simple as

```
print "Location:http://localhost:8000/index.html"
print ""
```

This isn't working for some reason. I'm running CGIHTTPServer on Kali Linux. I'm using Python 2.7.3
When I try to run the script it simply prints out

```
Location:http://localhost:8000/index.html
```

I have also tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It doesn't work either.Here is the CGI script that I'm trying to run

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb,cgi, os, sys
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="test")
flag=False
query = db.cursor()
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("")
sys.stdout.write("<html><body>")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('temp')
passwd = form.getvalue('temp2')

if(query.execute("select * from cred where uname='"+name+"' and pass='"+passwd+"'")):
    db.commit()
    sys.stdout.write("Hello "+name)

else:
    db.commit()
    flag=True
sys.stdout.write("</body></html>")

if(flag == True):
    print "Location:http://localhost:8000/"
    print ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems here:

1. You *always* write the `Content-Type` header *plus extra newlines* at the start. You've now completed all headers and you can no longer add more.

   Write these headers *only* when you are *not* redirecting.
2. A `Location` header is only used for redirects, a status 30x HTTP response. You'll need to add a `Status:` header to signal to the web server to respond with a status other than 200.

Adjusting your code to address these issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import MySQLdb, cgi, os, sys

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="test")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('temp')
passwd = form.getvalue('temp2')

with db as query:
    query.execute("select * from cred where uname=%s and %s", (name, passwd))
    result = query.fetchone()
    
if result is None:
    # no such user, redirect
    print 'Status: 302 Found'
    print 'Location: http://localhost:8000/'
    print

else:
    print 'Content-type: text/html'
    print
    print '<html><body>Hello {}</body></html>'.format(name)
```

Note that I altered the code somewhat to use some best practices:

1. **NEVER** use string interpolation to put user-information into a SQL query. You'll get hammered by a SQL injection attack that way. Use SQL parameters to have the database driver escape the values for you.
2. You can use the connection as a context manager to auto-commit.
3. I used string formatting to produce the HTML output.

Comment: I did all the changes as you asked me to, it isn't working yet. I get no errors on my server log and the web page displayed is just blank. Not to mention it did not redirect.

Comment: @user3905719: it looks as if your web server then does not honour the `Status:` header in that case; that's a violation of the CGI protocol. You can add a `Content-type: text/html` header, plus a `print '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost:8000" /></head></html>'` line to add a HTML body that *also* instructs the browser to redirect.

Comment: @user3905719: in modern browsers you can use the developer tools to look at what headers a server sent; look for the network tab.

Comment: Used the developer tools. It says Status text:200.Anyway I added the other header. Now it works just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted answer states, you'll need a `Status: 302 Found` or `Status: 301 Moved Permanently` header along with the `Location` header to do your redirect properly.

Also, the Python built-in CGIHTTPServer "cannot execute redirects (HTTP code 302), because code 200 (script output follows) is sent prior to execution of the CGI script. This pre-empts the status code." (https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html)

Unfortunately this is also the case in Python 3.  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)

There's a ticket about it (http://bugs.python.org/issue10487) but as of right now, there's no way to use the Status header.  This shouldn't be a problem with other CGI servers.

Comment: Good information about the CGIHTTPServer not supporting redirects, I could have spent hours scratching my head if I hadn't read your answer.